# hive - is it possible to create a column from another column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I was wondering if it is possible to create a new column from an existing column in hive.

Lets say I have a table `People (name string, age int)` and I want to add a column `is_old string` which would be defined as `if(age > 70, 'old', 'not_old')`.  Is there a way to do this?

The only way I can think of currently is to create a new table `People_temp` from the old one, delete the old table and rename the new table like so:

```
create table People_new as select name, age, if(age > 70, 'old', 'not_old') as is_old from People;
drop table People;
alter table People_new rename People;
```

**** Is there a way of doing this without creating a temp table?**
(for instance,  oracle has the idea of calculated columns.)

Comment: Yes.  Google hive case statement or Hive if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do it WITHOUT CREATING TEMP TABLE. Add column then insert overwrite table select from itself :

```
ALTER TABLE People ADD COLUMNS (is_old string);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE People 
SELECT name, age, if(age > 70, 'old', 'not_old') as is_old
  FROM People ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you should try it.

Use `CASE WHEN`:

```
,CASE WHEN age > 70 THEN ''old' ELSE 'not_old' END AS is_old string
```

use `IF`:

```
,IF(age > 70, 'old', 'not_old') AS is_old string
```